# chrome driver with selenium render error

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am just trying to get a simple test script working using selenium web driver and chrome driver. I have a maven project and when it kicks off my integration test the test fails with the following error

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
```

I am using selenium 2.44.0 with chromedriver 2.44

As my test is really simple I am a bit stuck here as to why it does not work

it falls over in this line in the setup method of my test

```
 driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

thanks in advance

UPDATE:

The test works fine when using the firefox driver. So issue is to do with the chromedriver specifically

my code is as below

```
package selenium.selenium_test;
import static junit.framework.Assert.*;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedCondition;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class SeleniumExampleTest {
  private String baseUrl;
  private WebDriver driver;
  private ScreenshotHelper screenshotHelper;

  @Before
  public void openBrowser() {
    //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/");
    //baseUrl = System.getProperty("webdriver.base.url");
      baseUrl = "http://www.google.com";
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    screenshotHelper = new ScreenshotHelper();
  }

  @After
  public void saveScreenshotAndCloseBrowser() throws IOException {
    screenshotHelper.saveScreenshot("screenshot.png");
    driver.quit();
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  @Test
  public void pageTitleAfterSearchShouldBeginWithDrupal() throws IOException {
    assertEquals("The page title should equal Google at the start of the test.", "Google", driver.getTitle());
    WebElement searchField = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    searchField.sendKeys("Drupal!");
    searchField.submit();
    assertTrue("The page title should start with the search string after the search.",
      (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
          return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("drupal!");
        }
      })
    );
  }

  private class ScreenshotHelper {

    public void saveScreenshot(String screenshotFileName) throws IOException {
      File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
      FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot, new File(screenshotFileName));
    }
  }
}
```

my pom file is as follows

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>selenium-test</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start-server</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <background>true</background>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>stop</id>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop-server</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Skip the normal tests, we'll run them in the integration-test phase -->
                    <skip>true</skip>

                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <webdriver.chrome.driver>src/test/resources/windows/chrome/chromedriver.exe</webdriver.chrome.driver>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>

                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
                <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
            <!-- dependency>
                <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
                <version>2.44.0</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
                        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency-->
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.44.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.opera</groupId>
            <artifactId>operadriver</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

console output from my test is as follows

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running selenium.selenium_test.SeleniumExampleTest
Starting ChromeDriver 2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf) on port 25865
Only local connections are allowed.
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.461 sec <<< FAILURE!
pageTitleAfterSearchShouldBeginWithDrupal(selenium.selenium_test.SeleniumExampleTest)  Time elapsed: 4.399 sec  <<< ERROR!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
  (Session info: chrome=40.0.2214.93)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.14.313457 (3d645c400edf2e2c500566c9aa096063e707c9cf),platform=Windows NT 6.1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 64 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf323ce037c5f92db6c1bba601c2ac43ad8', time: '2014-10-23 13:11:40'
System info: host: 'faisal-PC', ip: '172.22.1.150', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_17'
Session ID: 9e8efd2c32cd134b2858fffbc54da978
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\faisal\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir4164_7200}, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, version=40.0.2214.93, takesHeapSnapshot=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, webStorageEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:304)
    at selenium.selenium_test.SeleniumExampleTest.openBrowser(SeleniumExampleTest.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)

pageTitleAfterSearchShouldBeginWithDrupal(selenium.selenium_test.SeleniumExampleTest)  Time elapsed: 4.401 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at selenium.selenium_test.SeleniumExampleTest.saveScreenshotAndCloseBrowser(SeleniumExampleTest.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```